# Given f~g .Is it true that f+g~2g

Tags: calculus

Given $f\sim g$, is it true that $f+g\sim 2g$ ? .

My Attempt :

I think it is false as limit is not necessarily 1 ? I am not sure though..

Comment: It depends on the definition of ~. What does ~ mean in this context?

Comment: f~g means lim as x goes to zero f/g =1 ,

Comment: Then it is true. Write down the limit of $(f + g)/2g$

Comment: **Hint:** $\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{2g(x)} = \frac12\left[\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}+\frac{g(x)}{g(x)}\right]$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see:

$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{ f(x) + g(x)}{2g(x)} $

$= \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{2g(x)} + \frac{ g(x)}{2 g(x)} $

$= \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{2g(x)} + \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{ g(x)}{2 g(x)} $

$= \frac{1}{2}\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} + \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{ 1}{2}$

$= \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2} $

$= 1$.

So, yes, $f + g \sim 2g$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

\begin{align}
f(x)\sim_0 g(x)\\&\iff& f(x)-g(x)=o(g(x))\\&\iff&(f(x)+g(x))-2g(x)=o(2g(x))\\&\iff &f(x)+g(x)\sim_02g(x)\end{align}